# priority queue as max priority queue not working as expected

Tags: java

I was working on a [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-twitter/) question where we need to design the basic twitter functionality ,
such as follow and unfollow , post a tweet and newsfeed which will give the most recent 10 tweets for a user

postTweet(userId, tweetId): Compose a new tweet.
getNewsFeed(userId): Retrieve the 10 most recent tweet ids in the user's news feed. Each item in the news feed must be posted by users who the user followed or by the user herself. Tweets must be ordered from most recent to least recent.
follow(followerId, followeeId): Follower follows a followee.
unfollow(followerId, followeeId): Follower unfollows a followee.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;


class Twitter {

    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> followMap = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    Queue<Tweet> pQueue = new PriorityQueue<Tweet>((a, b)-> (int)(b.createdOn-a.createdOn));
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public Twitter() {

    }

    /** Compose a new tweet. */

    public void postTweet(int userId, int tweetId) {
        Tweet tweet = new Tweet(userId,tweetId, System.nanoTime());
        pQueue.add(tweet);
    }

    /** Retrieve the 10 most recent tweet ids in the user's news feed. Each item in the news feed must be posted by users who the user followed or by the user herself. Tweets must be ordered from most recent to least recent. */

    public List<Integer> getNewsFeed(int userId) {
        List<Integer> newsFeed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> follwedList = followMap.get(userId);
        List<Tweet> la = new ArrayList<Tweet>();
        while(pQueue.peek()!=null){

            Tweet element = pQueue.poll();
            if(newsFeed.size()==10){
                pQueue.addAll(la);
                return newsFeed;
            }
            if(element.userId == userId || (follwedList!=null && follwedList.contains(element.userId))){
                newsFeed.add(element.tweetId);
            }
            la.add(element);
        }
        pQueue.addAll(la);
        return newsFeed;
    }

    /** Follower follows a followee. If the operation is invalid, it should be a no-op. */

    public void follow(int followerId, int followeeId) {
        if(followMap.get(followerId)==null){
            List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            a.add(followeeId);
            followMap.put(followerId,a);
        }else{
            followMap.get(followerId).add(followeeId);
        }
    }

    /** Follower unfollows a followee. If the operation is invalid, it should be a no-op. */

    public void unfollow(int followerId, int followeeId) {
        if(followMap.get(followerId)!=null){
            for(int i=0;i<followMap.get(followerId).size();i++){
                if(followMap.get(followerId).get(i)==followeeId){
                    followMap.get(followerId).remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

class Tweet {
    int tweetId;
    int userId;
    long createdOn;
    Tweet(int userId, int tweetId, long createdOn){
        this.tweetId = tweetId;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }
}
```

the code work as expected for most of the test cases except one

["Twitter","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","postTweet","getNewsFeed","follow","getNewsFeed","unfollow","getNewsFeed"]
[[],[1,5],[2,3],[1,101],[2,13],[2,10],[1,2],[1,94],[2,505],[1,333],[2,22],[1,11],[1,205],[2,203],[1,201],[2,213],[1,200],[2,202],[1,204],[2,208],[2,233],[1,222],[2,211],[1](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-twitter/),[1,2],[1](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-twitter/),[1,2],[1](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-twitter/)]

My answer

[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[222,204,200,201,205,11,333,94,2,101],null,[211,222,233,208,204,202,200,213,201,203],null,[222,204,200,201,11,333,94,2,101,5]]

Expected answer

[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,[222,204,200,201,205,11,333,94,2,101],null,[211,222,233,208,204,202,200,213,201,203],null,[222,204,200,201,205,11,333,94,2,101]]

in the last news feed there is an error , for me 205 in not coming , but by design I expect it to be in the result , not sure why it is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your strategy correctly:

```java
            Tweet element = pQueue.poll();
            if(newsFeed.size()==10){
                pQueue.addAll(la);
                return newsFeed;
            }
            if(element.userId == userId || (follwedList!=null && follwedList.contains(element.userId))){
                newsFeed.add(element.tweetId);
            }
            la.add(element);
```

you have all tweets in `pQueue` and your `la` list keeps track of tweets that you have (temporarily) removed, and once your loop is complete, you add all those tweets in `la` back to the pQueue.

If so, then `la` does not contain all your removed tweets in the case that you reach newsFeed.size()==10. since you `return` early.

To fix this, you should probably have your `la.add(element)` right up where you `.poll()`